# pandas plot time series- strange line appears

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on an exchange rate data, and the result is very weird with unndeed lines appearing in the graph.

I have read through different samples, followed the samples and still cannot get rid of these lines.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?  Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
df = df[['PRICE', 'TIME']]
start_time = '2018-08-01 19:50:00'
end_time = '2018-08-01 20:10:00'

df = df[(df['TIME'] > start_time) & (df['TIME'] <= end_time)]
df = df.set_index('TIME')

plt.figure(figsize = (18,9))
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(df.index),df["PRICE"])
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Mid Price',fontsize=18)
```

If any data is needed, I saved the csv file in google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ANybvOKeUYIhXxtm97VNT88SI8z2OWjV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like some entries are unsorted

Comment: Thanks you are a genius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

used same data you provided

you need to add `df = df.sort_values(['TIME'], ascending=[True])`

**code:**

```
df = df[(df['TIME'] > start_time) & (df['TIME'] <= end_time)]
# df = df.drop_duplicates('TIME')
df = df.sort_values(['TIME'], ascending=[True])
df = df.set_index('TIME')

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 9))
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(df.index), df["PRICE"])
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Mid Price', fontsize=18)

plt.show()
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! problem solved. Have not noticed this pattern before that I need to sort my data before plotting. Thank you so much for your effort and time!

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce it, please ensure the csv file is the same:

```
df=pd.read_csv('a.csv', index_col=0, sep='\t')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.BID.plot()
```

[image]

Get similar plots for other columns too.